# What could possibly initiate the Amendments of Constitution?

Tags: united-states, constitution

If it is the oath below is true and correct

> I, [name], do solemnly swear that I will support and defend the Constitution of the United States against all enemies, foreign and domestic;

What could possibly initiate the Amendments of Constitution? Because there is more likely opposition of "resistance to amendment" will accuse to who initiate the amendment. How inaugural state of it can be done?

Comment: I don't follow what you are asking.  Are you asking if "defending the constitution" requires defending it from amendments?  It does not.  The constitution includes the ability to amend it.

Comment: Your name suggests you may be Italian. If you can edit your question to include an Italian version, I will happily translate it if nobody else gets to it before I do. The current English version of the question is almost impossible to make sense of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Article V of the United States Constitution](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Constitution_of_the_United_States_of_America#Article._V.):

> The Congress, whenever two thirds of both Houses shall deem it necessary, shall propose Amendments to this Constitution, or, on the Application of the Legislatures of two thirds of the several States, shall call a Convention for proposing Amendments, which, in either Case, shall be valid to all Intents and Purposes, as Part of this Constitution, when ratified by the Legislatures of three fourths of the several States, or by Conventions in three fourths thereof, as the one or the other Mode of Ratification may be proposed by the Congress

The President's oath of office is irrelevant to amending the Constitution for two reasons: first, the President has no part in amending it, and second, amending is part of the Constitution itself, so there's nothing to "defend" against.

Comment: I don't know if this is the right answer to the question, because I can't tell what it's actually asking.  That said, this is *likely* what they're trying to ask about.